# How to write a function for checkbox change event on save button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having multiple checkboxes in a grid. Initially some checkboxes are checked and some are unchecked. Then i will change the checkbox selection and i want to save the changed checkbox values in to the database. When i reopen the page i will display the checkboxes checked with the saved values.

The code i have written is:

```
    $(".check").each(function(){ 

           if (element.checked == true) {

                alert('checked');

            }

       });
```

The code works for checkbox event checked. but i want to also save the values that are changed(I mean checked to uncheked (means delete in the database))

Comment: are you unable to capture checkbox's change event?

Comment: no but i want to save those values in save click button event only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax for that purpose.

Hope this helps:

```
var listOfChecked= new Array();
var listOfUnchecked= new Array();
$(".check").each(function(){ 
    if (this.checked) {
        listOfChecked.push($(this).attr('value'));
    }
    else{
        listOfUnchecked.push($(this).attr('value'));
    }
});
$.get('mine.aspx?checkedValues='+listOfChecked.join(",")+'&uncheckedValues='+listOfUnchecked.join(","), function(data) {
    //saved
});
```

Comment: +'listOfChecked.join(",") should be +listOfChecked.join(",")

Comment: this.attr('value') should be $(this).attr('checked')

Comment: No. $(this).attr('checked') will return if its true or false. But this.attr('value') will return the value he specify. may be yes or no.

Comment: No, it will not return any value, it will give error "TypeError: this.attr is not a function"

Comment: to get value you have to use $(this).attr('value') instead of this.attr('value')

Comment: In that i will get all checked and unchecked values. But i want only changed values, Am i true